# ListView travando bastante no scroll

Tags: java, android

Minha ListView está travando bastante no scroll, já tentei implementar o ViewHolder ao Adapter mas não resolveu, poderiam me ajudar?

**Adapter:**

```
public class Adapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    private Context context;
    public LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public Adapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to)
    {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        HashMap<String, Object> data = (HashMap<String, Object>) super.getItem(position);

        if(view == null){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.clientes, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            viewHolder.title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            viewHolder.content = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.content);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }

        try {
            viewHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap( new DownloadTask().execute(data.get("thumbnail").toString()).get());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        viewHolder.title.setText(data.get("title").toString());
        viewHolder.content.setText(data.get("content").toString());

        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView title;
        TextView content;
    }
}
```

**DownloadTask:**

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bitmap image = null;

        try {
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( new URL(params[0]).openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: Já testou com a linha do `new DownloadTask()` comentada?

Comment: Se possível acrescente a implementação de DownloadTask. Pelo menos sua parte principal.

Comment: @Luídne, sim, sem setar uma imagem o ListView funciona perfeitamente, os travamentos ocorrem apenas quando utilizo a classe DownloadTask().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que o método [get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) do *AsyncTask* só retorna quando o método `doInBackground()` terminar. Você está a usar o *AsyncTask* de forma síncrona.

Altere a classe *DownloadTask* de forma a receber o `viewHolder.thumbnail` e faça o `setImageBitmap()` no método `onPostExecute()`.

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageView;

    public DownloadTask(ImageView thumbnail) {
        imageView = new WeakReference<ImageView>(thumbnail);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bitmap image = null;

        try {
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( new URL(params[0]).openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

        ImageView thumbnail = imageView.get();
        if (thumbnail != null) {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No *adapter* altere a linha

```
viewHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(new DownloadTask()
                       .execute(data.get("thumbnail").toString()).get());
```

para

```
new DownloadTask(viewHolder.thumbnail).execute(data.get("thumbnail").toString());
```

Comment: Realmente o desempenho melhorou, porém quando dou scroll na tela todos os itens da minha lista ficam com as thumbnails alterando como se fosse um slider, isto ocorre quando utilizo a função SetImageBitmap dentro da AsyncTask.

Comment: Isso é o comportamento esperado. Como a leitura dos *thumbnails* é assíncrona, a ListView não trava mas as imagens só vão ser mostradas após serem carregadas uma a uma. Não esqueça que o carregamento de uma imagem, de um *url*, é um processo demorado.

Comment: Uma forma de minimizar esse efeito é usar uma *cache* para guardar as imagens após terem sido descarregadas. Sempre que a *ListView* necessitar de apresentar uma imagem, a classe *DownloadTask* primeiro verifica se ela existe na *cache*, evitando que seja de novo descarregada.

Comment: O problema é que todas as posições na ListView parecem assumir a mesma thumbnail quando dou scroll, cada posição fica trocando da thumb como se fosse um slidershow de imagens. Vou tentar gravar um vídeo do que ocorre.

Comment: Vídeo: https://vid.me/u1Oc, perceba que as imagens ficam repetidas e as vezes trocando na mesma posição.

Comment: Ramaral respondeu muito bem sua questão inicial. Sugiro que você abra um outro tópico com a dúvida sobre o cache. Para assim podermos ajudar mais pessoas e organizar melhor as respostas. abs

Comment: As imagens ficam repetidas porque você está a reaproveitar as *Views* via o viewHolder. A solução é, antes de `new DownloadTask(viewHolder.thumbnail)` mostrar, na imageView, um ProgressBar. Veja [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341840/android-progress-bar-on-imageview) um exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que seu problema pode ser este aqui:

```
viewHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap( new DownloadTask().execute(data.get("thumbnail").toString()).get());
```

Estou supondo, pois não estou vendo sua implementação do DownloadTask. No Android todas as operações são realizadas na Main Thread, que é a thread da UI. Se você estiver fazendo qualquer operação de Bitmap nesta thread certamente o seu ViewHolder ficará muito lento e poderá inclusive travar a aplicação.

EDIT: Já vimos que o problema era mesmo o DownloadTask, mas agora você está com problemas para gerenciar corretamente o **cache do seus Bitmaps**. Para não ficar off topic eu sugiro que você abra uma nova discussão e dê esta por encerrada. Fica a sugestão de analisar alguma solução já testada em algum código, como o [Universal Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

Comment: Inclui o código da classe DownloadTask.

Comment: Estou no celular, então não tem como testar. Mas pelo visto o problema é o método mesmo. Acho que você deveria registrar um callback no seu asyncTask para retornar o resultado ao seu adapter e enquanto isso utilizar uma imagem "stub". Qualquer coisa te ajudou amanhã. Você me fala. Abs